# Create observer for Magento2.2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.2

**Create an observer file using this event.**

> sales_order_item_cancel

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $item */
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
        $children = $item->getChildrenItems();
        echo $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered() - max($item->getQtyShipped(), $item->getQtyInvoiced()) - $item->getQtyCanceled();
        exit;
        if ($item->getId() && $item->getProductId() && empty($children) && $qty) {
            $this->flag = "cancel";
            $this->cancelOrder = $item->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
            $this->stockManagement->backItemQty($item->getProductId(), $qty, $item->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        }
        $this->priceIndexer->reindexRow($item->getProductId());
        return $this;
    }
```

How to get `$this->flag` and `$this->cancelOrder` **values** in **observer file** using this event.

> cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after

```
if($this->flag == "cancel")
{
    $orderId = $this->cancelOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to set  **two variables** at `sales_order_item_cancel` observer class  **then get that value** to `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after`'s observer.

In this situation, you can use registry `\Magento\Framework\Registry` .
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-registry-register.html.

Create **two registry variable**  at `sales_order_item_cancel` 's observer and get that avriable value to `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after`